# Погрешность запуска cron задач

Tags: cron

Стоит задача на cron выполнение раз в час. Утром задача выполнялась ровно по direct-time.ruСейчас выполняется на несколько секунд раньше.

Тп хостинга ответили:

> Здравствуйте, в работе cron допускается погрешность в несколько секунд.

Мне важно что бы задача выполнялась не секундой раньше не позже исходя из времениdirect-time.ru

Как мне быть?

Comment: Я так понимаю direct-time.ru это не что то "волшебное" а сервер точного времени?! Ну попробуйте тогда например за 5 мин до начала задания, поставить синхронизацию с сервером точного времени по ntp.

Answer (score 2):

Если система не перегружена, часы синхронизированы без ошибок и дело только в cron'е, то можно попробовать запускать shell скрипт, в котором поставить цикл со sleep'ом и выходом из него с вызовом основного скрипта в установленное время.